# Open intervals are connected using a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

I have this problem which I can't solve it using the suggestion given.

> Using the continuous function $f(x)=$ $\frac{x}{1 + |x|}$ show that $(-1,1)$ is connected. Conclude that every open interval $(a,b)$ is connected.

I have solved this problem by a different way that what is suggested. I would like some hints to help me solve it using the given suggestion.What I can take for granted is that the rational numbers are not connected and that a closed interval is connected and the usual definitions of continuous functions.

If someone has already asked this or a similar answer please redirect me because I couldn't find it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you take it for granted that $\mathbb{R}$ is connected?

Comment: Yes! Forgot to add it, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two facts. The first one is that $\mathbb{R}$ is connected and the second one is that a continuous map preserves the connectedness.

Comment: Ok. So you say that because the function given is continuous and its domain is connected then if the image is the closed interval $(-1,1)$, by theorem it's closed. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly. So you should prove that $f(\mathbb{R})=(-1,1)$. Then, for the second part, you have that $(-1,1)$ is connected and you can find a continuous function that maps it to $(a,b)$ for any $a,b$.

Comment: So if I take the continuous function, $g(x)$ = ${\frac {b-a}{2}}x$  + ${\frac {b+a}{2}}$ which maps it to $(a,b)$ , then I will have completed the second part?

Comment: Yes!! It is also possible that you have to show that $g(x)$ is continuous, by the definition, use of $\epsilon$ and $\delta$.